# How and where do companies publish financial reports?

Tags: stock-exchanges, nasdaq

AFAIK, Wall-street companies should publish their financial reports and make them publicly available so that everyone can make an educated investment decision.
That might be a silly question but first of all : Is this true?
Secondly, and more importantly, WHERE are those news being published first?
eg. Let's say that I'm a NASDAQ company (let's say Coca-Cola) and I want to make  my financial report publicly available. Where and how do i go about that? :)

Comment: You can find most of that stuff on Yahoo Finance, if you are just looking for the data.  Not sure about the overall process.

Comment: http://www.coca-colacompany.com/investors

Comment: quid the question was generally to any company,unless you are saying that the first place where Coca Cola publishes the reports is their own server?

Comment: Its hard to tell where the information will appear first.  I tend try the company's investor relations website rather than stumbling around on EDGAR.  Most large companies will have an investor relations site, but not necessarily all.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is true. The US based companies have to meet the requirements placed on them by the US government. The agency with all these reports is the Security and Exchange Commission.

They run the [EDGAR system](https://www.sec.gov/investor/pubs/edgarguide.htm) to hold all those required reports

> The SEC’s EDGAR database provides free public access to corporate
>   information, allowing you to quickly research a company’s financial
>   information and operations by reviewing registration statements,
>   prospectuses and periodic reports filed on Forms 10-K and 10-Q. You
>   also can find information about recent corporate events reported on
>   Form 8-K but that a company does not have to disclose to investors.
>
> EDGAR also provides access to comment and response letters relating to
>   disclosure filings made after August 1, 2004, and reviewed by either
>   the Division of Corporation Finance or the Division of Investment
>   Management. On May 22, 2006, the staffs of the Divisions of
>   Corporation Finance and Investment Management began to use the EDGAR
>   system to issue notifications of effectiveness for Securities Act
>   registration statements and post-effective amendments, other than
>   those that become effective automatically by law. These notifications
>   will be posted to the EDGAR system the morning after a filing is
>   determined to be effective.

As pointed out by Grade 'Eh' Bacon: Other countries may require different types of information to be reported to the public, in particular, financial statements. To find the financial statements released for a particular company, you can go to the appropriate stock exchange, or often simply the company's corporate website.

Comment: Thank you, however according to this question and answer http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/where-do-company-filings-go-first , apparently this is not the first place where it is available. Or is this illegal and shouldn't be happening? I thought that the idea is that it should be available to everyone at the same time, so how come if I'm paying I'm getting the info before all the public?!

Comment: In other words: My original question is asking where and how it is published first. If the answer is EDGAR,and available to everyone then there's something wrong with the other answer...I'm so confused :P

Comment: The answers on the other question makes it clear, it is released to everybody at the same time. What happens next, depends on how much you are willing to pay.

Comment: Not clear to me :( See,if you will look at EDGAR's API FAQ here: http://developer.edgar-online.com/faq#id103 then the data is being updated only once a day,at 3am at that!! So....where exactly is this released at the same time to everyone, and what are people paying for if it is available already? :P

Comment: EDGAR is the official site/service maintained by the Securities and Exchange Commission, to which companies must **first** post their financial reports before releasing them to the general public.  If that data's available anywhere other than EDGAR first, there's something not right happening, and it's probably illegal.

Comment: @YoniKeren your link says that EDGAR data available via the API is only updated every day at 3am EST, not that all data on the system is only updated at that time.  As an example Apple's most recent 10Q was accepted at: 2016-07-27 16:32:36.

Comment: @DanielAnderson do you have a citation for that claim?  There's a deadline by which a corporation must file certain reports but I'm not aware of a requirement that the filing be submitted to the SEC before it is publicly disclosed.  It seems a regulation restricting public disclosure would be counter intuitive...

Comment: Here's something that can help:  http://www.legalandcompliance.com/securities-resources/sec-requirements-for-public-companies/

Comment: @DanielAnderson, that only speaks to deadlines under which an issuer must report to the SEC, not that there's a prohibition on disclosing information somewhere other than the SEC, like a company investor relation website, first.

Comment: There is, though.  I'll see if I can look up the specific rule and get back to you with it.  Thanks for following up and keeping me on my toes! (smile)